# Most efficent way to move a directory in haskell

Tags: file, haskell, io

What is the most efficient way to move a directory and all its contents?

Is there a more efficient way then just looping each file in the directory and calling `System.Directory.renameFile`  on it?

Comment: Voting to reopen as the question has been reworded from "best" to something quantifiable, ie "efficient".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `System.Directory.renameDirectory`

```
λ System.Directory.getDirectoryContents "temp2"
[".","..","x","y"]
λ System.Directory.renameDirectory "temp2" "temp"
λ System.Directory.getDirectoryContents "temp"
[".","..","x","y"]
```